# What are the options for self-service password reset with Forefront Identity Manager?

Tags: c#, security, active-directory, identity

I haven’t really worked a lot with AD, and not at all with FIM, but I’m now in a situation where we as a team need to provide some options for a customer that would like to have a self-service system for password reset. FIM is already in place and being used for some synchronization things, and it has been decided that we will be using FIM. The question is how.

Here is the ideal
A custom application that is accessible from:

- After login in a browser
- On an external device
- From the login screen (see separate discussion on this)

We are using the following to identify the users:

- ID (work)
- Security questions
- Magnetstripe card (optional)
- Personal details
- We are considering SMS identification as well, but only 20% of the users have a registered phone

Here are the options we have come up with so far, with our thoughts:

1. FIM out of the box self-service works and provides a login screen link to change the password – which we really want. The GUI on the other hand isn’t very customizable and doesn’t provide the user experience we want. You can only change colors, fonts and logo. We would like to freely customize the look, and workflow.
2. Web application that after all required details are filled in provides a temporary password that will require immediate password reset once logged in. Email will notify user about password change attempt, and lock for further attempts ant notify support if more than 3 attempts are made within a day.
   This does however not provide a login on the screen, which is a feature we were hoping for. Talks to FIM services on the backend.
3. SMS password reset service based on the same concept as above. Not really an option since we have few registered phones. Talks to FIM services on the backend.
4. A login hook that takes the user to the browser to the application (not FIM app, but uses FIM services). The worry here is creating a security risk by changing the login screen, and also how to roll out the solution, and how OS updates will affect us. But most of all, the feedback I’ve gotten from other developers is that this is a pretty bad idea.

Here are the questions:
**

1. Are we missing some other options?
2. What should be our biggest concern?
3. And which option would be best?

** – We define best as the option that fulfills these criteria’s, in order of importance:

- Secure
- User friendly
- Maintainable
- Less costly to implement/less time

Any information is greatly appreciated, hope I’ve provided enough information. Happy to adjust the text/question if it’s not scoped clearly enough.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, FIM comes with a Self-Service Password Reset Portal.

You can find the documentation (plan/deploy/maintain)on TechNet:
 http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj134309(v=ws.10).aspx

See also this TechEd talk: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-p41Ze9ewA

--larsw

Comment: Thank you Lars, we know of that one- its the first option described in my question. The interface isn't very customizable and that is why we want to take a look at all the options.Ive seen the teched talk, its a very basic intro to FIM with as-is examples.